# Authorize Rrecurring billing subscribes

Tags: magento, authorize.net, recurring-billing

Can I configure my recurring billing that customers can pay for subscribe not every month but for example: 1 pay,after 35 days next pay, and after 50 day next pay?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Authorize.Net Recurring Billing does not currently support non-standard intervals.  See https://developer.authorize.net/api/reference/#recurring-billing